# Issue with deserializing data using RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, restsharp

I'm having some difficulty deserializing data returned from a web service via RestSharp. Below is the data returned from a POST request.

```
{
"responseCPUTime": "0",
"response": "PASS",
"responseFor": "getSalesOrders",
"responseData": {
"salesOrders": [
  {
            "loadStatus": "",
            "comments": "",
            "modifyDate": "20180130",
            "custShipToID": "",
            "invoiceCount": "0",
            "custBillToID": "WINDJ",
            "invoiceAmount": "12280.00",
            "pickDate": "20180204",
            "warehouse": "~D",
            "custName": "WINN DIXIE JACKSONVILLE",
            "modifyTime": "102614",
            "loadID": "",
            "createTime": "075610",
            "createdBy": "RGN",
            "custPONum2": "",
            "modifiedBy": "KAL",
            "SONum": "00855494",
            "deliveryDate": "20180205",
            "tripNumber": "",
            "custPONum": "66523",
            "status": "O",
            "createDate": "20180125"
            },
              {
            "loadStatus": "",
            "comments": "",
            ......
            }
            ],
    },
"responseMessage": ""
}
```

Here is the model I'm trying to deserialize the data into.

Model:

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    public string loadStatus { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string modifyDate { get; set; }
    public string custShipToID { get; set; }
    public string invoiceCount { get; set; }
    public string custBillToID { get; set; }
    public string invoiceAmount { get; set; }
    public string pickDate { get; set; }
    public string warehouse { get; set; }
    public string custName { get; set; }
    public string modifyTime { get; set; }
    public string loadID { get; set; }
    public string createTime { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string custPONum2 { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string SONum { get; set; }
    public string deliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string tripNumber { get; set; }
    public string custPONum { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string createDate { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseData
{
    public List<SalesOrder> salesOrders { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string responseCPUTime { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string responseFor { get; set; }
    public ResponseData responseData { get; set; }
    public string responseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the class that successfully fetches the data but cannot seem to load into a List of SalesOrderModel.

Class:

```
 public List<SalesOrderModel> GetSalesOrders(string company, string custBillToID, string startShipDate, string endShipDate)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com");
        var request = new RestRequest("xxx/services", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("header", @"accept: application/json
                                        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
                                        accept-language: en-US, en; q=0.8
                                        content-type: application/json
                                        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");

        request.AddParameter("appId", "xxxxxx");
        request.AddParameter("command", "getSalesOrders");
        request.AddParameter("company", "0007");
        request.AddParameter("startDeliveryDate", "20180205");
        request.AddParameter("endDeliveryDate", "20180205");
        request.AddParameter("status", "O");


        IRestResponse <List<SalesOrderModel>> response = client.Execute<List<SalesOrderModel>>(request);
        return response.Data;

    }
```

Can anyone point me into the direction as to how to properly map the data returned into a model class?

Thanks

Edit: I updated my model to include a 'wrapper' of sorts.

Now my question is, what is the best way to access this data in a view?

**Edit**:
View:

```
@model DirectOrderTracker.Models.RootObject


@foreach (var item in @Model.responseData.salesOrders)
{
    @item.custBillToID
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json and the model which are deserialized is incompitable. You are trying to deserialize non-collection json as a collection like `List`. So, modify your model like this;

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    public string loadStatus { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string modifyDate { get; set; }
    public string custShipToID { get; set; }
    public string invoiceCount { get; set; }
    public string custBillToID { get; set; }
    public string invoiceAmount { get; set; }
    public string pickDate { get; set; }
    public string warehouse { get; set; }
    public string custName { get; set; }
    public string modifyTime { get; set; }
    public string loadID { get; set; }
    public string createTime { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string custPONum2 { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string SONum { get; set; }
    public string deliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string tripNumber { get; set; }
    public string custPONum { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string createDate { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseData
{
    public List<SalesOrder> salesOrders { get; set; }
}

public class JsonObject
{
    public string responseCPUTime { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string responseFor { get; set; }
    public ResponseData responseData { get; set; }
    public string responseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize it like `JsonObject`;

```
IRestResponse<JsonObject> response = client.Execute<JsonObject>(request);
```

Comment: Yeah I found that json2c# converter. Great tool.

Comment: My question is now, what is the best way to access this data in a view?

Comment: Pass the returned data to the view via model.

Comment: Figured as much. Thanks for the help